# deleting selected row from the gridview using dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I am using a gridview and in the gridview im using a dropdown list.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-top:auto">
    <br /><br /><br />
    <asp:GridView ID="grdUser" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CaptionAlign="Left" OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="grdUser_Sorting" PageSize="5" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#9999FF" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#009933" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" Mode="NumericFirstLast" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="4" NextPageText="" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFF66" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAct_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Action">Action</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Activate">Activate</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Block">Block</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Delete">Delete</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

ok so now i want to hide the selected row from the grid when i am on a specific row.

Code is :

```
 public void GetDataTable()
{

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FacebookConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select F_Name AS [First Name], S_Name AS [Surname], E_Mail AS [Email], Day+'-'+Month+'-'+Year AS [Birthday], Gender AS [Gender] from Users Order By F_Name";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Load(dr);

            grdUser.DataSource = dt;
            grdUser.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

for dropdown selected index change what i have to do ? please help me .

```
protected void ddlAct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // what i'll be doing here ?   
}
```

Comment: Side-note: either the name of the method or the return type is wrong: `public void GetDataTable()`. I hope that `DataTable dt` is not `static`. You should really create and fill it in the method and then return it. The caller can bind it to the `GridView` as `DataSource`.

Comment: Where do you store the UserID or the Email at all? You need an identifier for the row. If it should be hidden you can use a `HiddenField` in another `TemplateField` or if it should be shown a `Label`. Then use `ddl.NamingContainer` to get the `GridViewRow` and `row.FindControl("LblEmail")` to get the reference to the other control. You can use it to delete this record from database and load it again via `GetDataTable`

Comment: i don't want to delete it from the database at all

Comment: also my dropdownlist name is ddlAct but it's not showing in the code